# How to Set Default splash image for both iOS 6 & iOS 7 version in same App

Tags: ios6, ios7, xcode5

I am re-skinning my Application to make it iOS 7 compatible & also work for iOS 6 with old layout. So basically it will have different layouts for iOS 6 & 7.

Now I want to set default Splash screen for both version separate images.

Can anyone suggest me the best way for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]If you use the asset manager, you have a list of possible images to use for iOS 7 as well as iOS 5 and 6. You can set these as you will.

If you create a new launch image you are given placeholders for all the possible devices and sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 loading screen images are different size for the iPad. So there should not be any problem there.

You can use an assets catalog to load different screen for iOS 5/6 and iOS 7.